# Does MongoDB version 4.4 support $text search within $lookup?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, lookup

I am trying to do a text search within $look up. I remember in a previous version (version 4.0) this was not possible. Here is an example of what I'm trying to accomplish. Does MongoDB version 4.4 support $text search within $lookup?

```
db.getCollection('recording').aggregate([
 {
   "$lookup": {
     "from": "meeting",
     "let": {
       "meetingId": "$meeting"
     },
     "as": "meeting_data",
     "pipeline": [
       {
         "$match": {
           "_id": "$$meeting",
           "$text": {
             "$search": "\"go away\""
           }
         }
       }
     ]
   }
 },
 {
   "$lookup": {
     "from": "transcribe",
     "let": {
       "transcribeId": "$transcribe"
     },
     "as": "transcribe_data",
     "pipeline": [
       {
         "$match": {
           "_id": "$$transcribeId",
           "$text": {
             "$search": "\"go away\""
           }
         }
       }
     ]
   }
 }
])
```

previous error

```
   {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "pipeline requires text score metadata, but there is no text score available",
        "code" : 40218,
        "codeName" : "Location40218"
    }
```

Comment: This is possible in MongoDB version 4.4 and 4.2. You will need to use $expr as suggested below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try this, it runs fine for me in `4.4.1`. I just re-wrote the variables:

```
pipeline = [
    {
        "$lookup" : {
            "from" : "meeting",
            "let" : {
                "meetingId" : "$meeting"
            },
            "as" : "meeting_data",
            "pipeline" : [
                {
                    "$match" : {
                        "$expr" : {
                            "$eq" : [
                                "$_id",
                                "$$meetingId"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "$text" : {
                        "$search" : "\"go away\""
                    }
                }}]
            }}]
            



db.getCollection('recording').aggregate(pipeline)
```

If it works, follow same idea for the next stage.